# How to debug a solution in visual studio without deploying it

Tags: 2013, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I'm running:
Visual Studio 2013,
Sharepoint 2013 and 
Microsoft SQL server 2012.

I'm a beginer and I would like to know how to use the debug tool properly.
I'm trying to debug my solution in visual studio 2013 and every time I'm clicking on the "start" button after adding a few breakpoints, it's trying to deploy the solution (and fail) without even stopping on the breakpoints. They are reachable.

I did Attached the code to the process that are required and configured the web.config file with the right options:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" /> 
<SafeMode MaxControls="200" CallStack="true"... AllowPageLevelTrace="false"> 
<compilation debug="true">
```

Comment: Does your project build successfully? i.e. right click the project name and select build.

Comment: Yes it does. Actully I need to build the solution, publish it, update it and then start the debug mode. Without forgeting to attach the web process required. I wasn't making all steps in the proper order or incompletely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) From the Build menu in Visual Studio: click Build / Configuration Manager, then select Debug or Release.

2) On the toolbar, choose either Debug or Release from the Solution Configurations list box.

3) In the Configuration Manager window uncheck the "deploy" option for the choosen mode.

[Source from msdn here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not be executed until the solution is successfully deployed. If there are errors with the deployment process, you will need to resolve those first.